# How to use AHCI SATA linux driver for an application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sata

I have an application running which has the requirement to use SATA AHCI driver for linux. I have got AHCI.so to be used but I'm looking for some file(.h file)which will publishing the api's which my appication can use(Planning to write a glue layer to communicate with .SO using api).

Can anybody help me in identifying right file which will be publishing all api's of AHCI.SO or I have to write such file by my own.

Answer (score 1):

fopen, fwrite, fread, fclose.  If the target drive is in ahci mode then you will use the ahci drivers.

Comment: That was my first thought when reading the question. Have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your response but not sure this what i'm looking for ,In qnx based support we have "libdevb-ahciS.a" and file "devb_api.h" will be pubishing api's of "libdevb-ahciS.a" which in turn can be used by any application to use ahci based driver code .is it same true for linux envirnoment?

Comment: It sounds like you are using non-standard APIs in qnx and those same APIs certainly will not exist in Linux. You should look at this as an opportunity to port your code to standard APIs.